# Storing hex value in C string?

Tags: c, binary, gdb, hex

I have a string `"SOMETHING /\xff"` and I want to save the hex representation of `0xff` into a `char` buffer.  So I `strncpy` everything after the forward slash (`/`) into my buffer (let's call it `buff`).

However, when I use the gdb command `print \x buff` to view the contents of `buff`, it doesn't show `0xff`.  Any ideas as to what could be wrong?  Is it possible that my forward slash is messing things up?

Comment: This is not clear.  As was already explained in answers to your previous questions, `\xff` is not literally stored in the string.  A single character (whose value is 255) is stored in its place.

Comment: The forward slash shouldn't affect the following characters.  What _does_ gdb show in the buffer?

Comment: Do you have any code to go with that paragraph?

Comment: Can you show the code and what you get and what you are expecting to see?

Comment: What are you trying to store? Do you want `"0xff"` in your string or do you want the value `FF` stored in a byte of your buffer?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth what does the 255 mean?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth and would this single character only take up only half a byte?

Comment: @AusCBloke I would like the value FF stored

Comment: The character `\xFF` (ie, a character with the decimal value 255) isn't going to print as a visible character in most cases.

Comment: @Nosrettap: No, it would take a byte.

Comment: @Nosrettap: That's what you're doing, you're probably not printing that single byte as hex in gdb, or your `strncpy` code is wrong.

Comment: gdb gives me the hex values `0x5c, 0x78, 0x66, 0x66` when I try to store the string "\x99 HTTP".  Any ideas?

Comment: @Nosrettap: You sure that's not the address of the string?

Comment: @AusCBloke I got this by writing in gdb `print /x bufferName`

Comment: @Nosrettap: If your buffer is of type `char*`, then I think you might be printing it wrong in gdb, check my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem has to do with the way you're printing the variable in gdb. Take this simple program, compile as debug (`-g` if using gcc), and run and break at the first `puts` statement:

```
int main(void)
{
   char *ptr = "str \xff";
   char arr[] = "str \xff";
   puts(ptr);
   puts(arr);

   return 0;
}
```

If I try and print `ptr` the way you've mentioned, `p /x ptr`, it'll print the value of `ptr` (the address it's pointing to):

```
(gdb) p /x ptr
$1 = 0x4005f8
```

However if I do the same command for `arr`, I'll get:

```
(gdb) p /x arr
$2 = {0x73, 0x74, 0x72, 0x20, 0xff, 0x0}
```

That's because gdb can see that `arr` is of type `char[6]` and not `char*`. You can get the same results with the command `p /x "str \xff"`, which is useful for testing things:

```
(gdb) p /x "str \xff"
$3 = {0x73, 0x74, 0x72, 0x20, 0xff, 0x0}
```

Now if you want to be able to print a certain amount of bytes from the address pointed to by a pointer, use the examine (`x`) memory command instead of print (`p`):

```
(gdb) x/6bx ptr
0x4005f8 <__dso_handle+8>:  0x73    0x74    0x72    0x20    0xff    0x00
```

That'll print 6 bytes in hex from the address pointed to by `ptr`. Try that with your `buff` variable and see how you go.

Alternatively, another thing you can try is:

```
(gdb) p /x (char[6])*ptr
$4 = {0x73, 0x74, 0x72, 0x20, 0xff, 0x0}
```

This will treat the `char` pointed to by `ptr` as the first element in an array of 6 `char`s, and will allow you to use the print command.

Answer (score 0):

0xFF is not a printable ASCII character, so gdb can't print it.

Answer (score -2):

Keep in mind that a string in C is an array of `char` values.  And a `char` is an unsigned 8-bit quantity.  (Just as an `int` is a signed 16-bit quantity.)  The maximum value that can be placed in an unsigned 8-bit field is 255 decimal which is 0xFF hex or 0377 octal or 11111111 binary.

Within a quoted character string in C, the notation `\xNN` means to insert the character whose hex value is NN.

Comment: -1; Nothing in the standard says that `char` is unsigned, and nothing in the standard says that it must be 8 bits or that `int` must be 16 bits. In fact, in most compilers these days, `int`s are 32 bits.